# Failed: invalid argument -Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

Trying to write a simple Automation script to navigate to a link by opening browser

using Chrome

it throws Failed: invalid argument when using browser.get(link)

I think the issue is with driver version

so Treid updating webdriver-manager and also chrome but nothing worked

below are used config file and the error

Changed the names of files theres no conflict with names
assume they are same wherever used

```
  specsFile
    describe('Affiliate', function() {

        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

        it('Convert to links', function(){

            browser.get('https://www.google.com/');
        })

    });
```

Theres nothing much in specfile

```
Config File


exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
        binary: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable',
          args: ["--disable-notifications","--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600", "--no-sandbox" ]
      }
    },
    specs: ['../Scripts/specsFile.spec.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true,
    }
};
```

Error

```
[02:51:35] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[02:51:35] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
.F

Failures:
1) sample
  Message:
    Failed: invalid argument
      (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
    System info: host: 'hey', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.0.0-29-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
  Stack:
    WebDriverError: invalid argument
      (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
    System info: host: 'hey', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.0.0-29-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    From: Task: WebDriver.navigate().to()
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:807:17)
        at Navigation.to (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1133:25)
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:988:28)
        at ProtractorBrowser.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:655:32)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/home/hey/NodeJsWorkSpace/Scripts/specsFile.spec.js:13:17)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1077:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2505:12)
        at schedulerExecute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
    From: Task: Run it("Convert to links") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/hey/NodeJsWorkSpace/Scripts/specsFile.spec.js:11:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hey/NodeJsWorkSpace/Scripts/specsFile.spec.js:1:63)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)

2 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 0.174 seconds

[02:51:36] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[02:51:36] I/launcher - firefox #01 failed 1 test(s)
[02:51:36] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[02:51:36] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code? The config file sees to be okay.

Comment: Try commenting selenium address and use directConnect: true

Comment: If you are using latest protractor version, disable the control flow and use async/await.